# container inside a navbar in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a following navbar code using twitter bootstrap

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the output is
[image: With original bootstrap]
When I remove "width: auto" from ".navbar .container{width:auto}" in bootstap.css the output becomes
[image: After the hack]
and is the output I am expecting.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2093 shows "width: auto" as an intended feature.What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should do it

Comment: An html and accessible friendly version would use `<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">` as the outer most container (per [Bootstrap 3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)).

Comment: role="navigation" is considered redundant.http://html5doctor.com/on-html-belts-and-aria-braces/

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution to the above issue.

Add `navbar-fixed-top` class to the main `navbar` div.

And add

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
position: relative;
}
```

to your css rule.

This restricts the menu from pulling it to the left and worked fine while I was developing a theme for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Bootstrap basic nav bar example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) you will see that there is a margin on either side of the navbar. This is because for a non-fluid container, your page will occupy a fixed width and the navbar uses that width.

If you want the navbar to extend across the entire page, you need to use a `class="container-fluid"` but in a fluid layout, the menu items (by default) will flow from the left-hand side of the page.

In your code, you are using both `container` and `container-fluid` which is incorrect, and as per the Bootstrap documentation, you need to place the nav in a container - not embed a container in your nav tags.

Comment: I want the navbar to occupy the entire screen width but the contents (menu items) should be inside the container. Removing "container-fluid" will not fix this issue. If I put nav inside a container, the bar will be only 70% of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the `width: auto` definition from `.navbar .container` in `bootstrap.css`.

Not an ideal solution (editing `bootstrap.css` in general) but it was much simpler than applying all the responsive widths to the selector.